# Batch delete after persisting uri chosen by user in ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android

I am moving from file API to SAF for Android 11+ devices only (I will continue using the file API for previous systems). I have learned that I can ask the user to select a folder/directory using SAF (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) then persist it so I no longer have to ask the user for access to the folder/directory he picked. Now, I am facing a design issue where I cannot use `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest()` for batch deletion on Android 11+ design. I need to be able to detect user allowing or cancelling deletion on `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest()` but it seems to be not possible to do. My question is. Is it possible to use the persisted uri to batch delete files within the persisted uri without asking the user for permission to delete each file one by one and thus bypassing the limitation of `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest()`

Comment: You can delete any file you want without requesting any further permission if you use saf. If you manage to call createDeleteRequest with all uries for your files the user only has to confirm the delete once. You talk about a limitation but what do you mean. One confirmation is all the user has to give.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the reply. My issue is caused by the inability to handle accept/cancel dialogs of `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest` I want to handle the accept or cancel with two different approaches. If the user accepts, I would refresh the UI and update my internal lists while the delete is being carried out. `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest` doesn't allow me to check that. Also, there is the nuisance of having to rely on `onActivityResult` which would force me to clutter my app design which I do not want. That is why I am looking for alternative using the SAF. Thanks again.

Comment: `while the delete is being carried out.` There is no while. This is executed very fast. And you can update the gui afterwards in onActivityResult. I have no idea where you are against.

Comment: @blackapps It is not fast when you have many items to remove. I want my users to be able to see the up to date UI directly after the delete instead of seeing the action of refreshing it being carried out after the delete. Also, as I have mentioned before, `onActivityResult` is not favorable for me because of the way the app is designed. That is why I am looking into SAF. Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1000 files in less than two seconds. What do you wanna update. Its blistery fast. You can never do that yourself that fast using saf. One file per second about.